# how to keep django models in database for users customized view?

Tags: python, django, django-models

suppose i have three models, at my view I am showing all the item of these models, i want to give my user privilege to set which model's objects are to be shown at view at first, second and third.

what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

A best practice in Django is to have user profile objects defined like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    # add whatever other configurations & preferences you allow the user to set here
    feature_x_priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    feature_y_priority = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    feature_z_priority = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

Then from any point in your code you can use `user.profile.feature_x_priority`

Don't forget to create a profile for every user (new & existing) or you will have check for existance of `user.profile` prior to using it.

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what you mean by "my user" .

is this just the admin user who set this configuration globaly for the site .

or do you mean evey user of the site has his/her own preferences ?

if the latter case then make a new model called `Preferences` which has `one to one` relation to the user model .

then in your query you should create three separate queries according to the preference values .